# convert iphone App to IPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I just completed one app in iPhone, now I wants to create same app for both iPhone and iPad.

I am new in iPhone, So don't know exact what to do?

1) create the new project and select Universal option, and copy paste all code

2) modify this app for both.

How to add xib for iPad?

[image]

thanks

Comment: You can do either , modify it for ipad coz d iphone one is already made rite....

Comment: @TejeshwarGill. thanks for reply. I know detect device on run time. but how i can add xib for iPad in current project?

Comment: sorry typing mistake. for iPad

Comment: Ok go to ur Project-> New File ->User Interface->New-> Iphone/IPad... choose accordingly...

Comment: i add the screen shot. i not find the  Project-> New File ->User Interface->New-> Iphone/IPad

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16352/discussion-between-tejeshwar-gill-and-stackblue)

Comment: @TejeshwarGill thanks for help. i got the option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct,

1. Select the **Universal** option.
2. Transfer code from the existing iPhone project to the new project.
   NOW,
3. Make the **xib** files for iPad, and make the connections (IBOutlets).
4. Wherever you need platform specific features (eg. Popover, Split ViewController etc for iPad), put an `IF` statement to handle the device specific features.

Comment: thanks. I have a problem when i make new project. how i add Xib for iPad?

Comment: sorry typing mistake.. it's Ipad

Comment: how we make xib files for iPad. can you explain?

Comment: Go to: X-Code File-> New -> New File -> View [Select **iPad** as Device Family] . Give a filename to the Xib and click on create. Voila, you're done!

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [this blog post](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.de/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html) gives you a quick overview, when you want to convert. Otherwise you can create a new project, of course, and copy your code.

Answer (score 0):

Select View From User Interface Option after that choose iPad from Device Family. This will create Xib for iPad.And then in Files Owner connect your class.