# How to design application for ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7

I want to design my application for ipad.I have my application compatible with iphone 4 and iphone 5.Now for Ipad  does I have to design different screen for ipad and ipad mini?? Can Anyone guide me on that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert iphone App to IPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296805/convert-iphone-app-to-ipad)

Comment: The ipad, ipad retina as well as ipad mini will use the same design.

Comment: Yes, only one XIB will be needed which will be used for all kinds or iPad. The coordinate system for retina is converted internally hence you do not have to worry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *iPad mini 2012* has a resolution of `1024 * 768`. This is the same resolution as iPad 1 and 2 (**non-retina**).

The *iPad mini 2013* has a resolution of `2048 * 1536`. This is the same resolution as all newer iPads (**retina**).

So you can treat an iPad mini just like a regular iPad.

Comment: If this helped you 20 months ago, feel free to accept it ;)

Comment: you can see question is marked as CLOSED... :D